# height of a tableview cell change dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

If textview inside a tableview then tell me the code for editForRowAtIndexPath method## Heading ##
**UITextView in a UITableViewCell: update the cell height dynamically*

Comment: There are many posts on updating the cell height dynamically.  Just search StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the Cell height dynamically youcan use this function,
And add @protocol UITableViewDelegate

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90;
}
```